# Am I really dealing with panel data?

Tags: panel-data, cross-section

I am working with a dataset that consists of multiple transactions from the multiple individuals over a span of roughly three years. From my research I understand that cross sectional data is rather a snapshot of a specific period. Logically I would assume than that what I am dealing with is panel data. However, most individuals are involved in only two transactions (a purchase and a sale). Does this already make the dataframe panel data or would I have to create that myself by lets say creating a variable "portfolio value" for every period, lets say a year and then would have three observations per ID? Also could I still run a regular regression or would this not bring any valuable insigths?

The data looks somewhat like this and as can be seen, some IDs are involved in multiple transactions. What I did so far was regress lets say

ROI (return on investment) = a bunch of variables like transaction count etc.

[image]

I hope this is somewhat clear and am thankful for any help.